Higher timeframe zigzag leg from tradingview zigzag library
I need to know how can get Higher timeframe zigzag leg(segment) from tradingview ZigZag library.
I'd be appriciate if you could reply with a simple example by using this library.
https://www.tradingview.com/script/bzIRuGXC-ZigZag/
I don't know how to get the zigzag segments from higher timeframe and draw them on current timeframe.

That's not so easy. You need to get the price action from the higher timeframe and find the pivots yourself on the lower timeframe. You should also keep track of which lower timeframe bar corresponds to the pivot high/low of the higher timeframe bar so you can draw properly.
